# i cant copy text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

am working with asp.net and i want to copy values in a input element using javascript but its not working.
here is my code and see if i got it wrong.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Company</label>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" style="color:#000; font-weight:700;" class="form-control" id="myInput" readonly="">
                </div>
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Click to copy</button>
```

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
            var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
            copyText.select();
            copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
            document.execCommand("copy");
            alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
        }
```

edited
the input field is to be filled from the back end and i don't want the user to edit it so i can't remove readonly.

Answer (score 0):

remove the readonly and you're good to go!

```js
function myFunction() {
            var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
            copyText.select();
            copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
            document.execCommand("copy");
            alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Company</label>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" style="color:#000; font-weight:700;" class="form-control" id="myInput" >
                </div>
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Click to copy</button>
```

Comment: the input field is to be filled from the back end and i don't want the user to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have default value in the input field but also make it read-only, you may set the input field as follow:

```
<input
  type="text"
  runat="server"
  style="color:#000; font-weight:700;"
  class="form-control"
  id="myInput"
  value="Some default value"
  readonly
/>
```

Otherwise, remove the `readonly` attribute and allow it to be modified by user.

Also, I believe `copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)` is redundant.

Comment: the input field is to be filled from the back end and i don't want the user to edit it.

Comment: You can do so like what I wrote in my code snippet, fill the value attribute and add the readonly attribute.